# What is $E[\log(Z!)]$ when $Z$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda$?

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation, poisson-distribution

Suppose $Z$ is a discrete random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, and for $\lambda>0$, $Z$ is distributed as Poisson with rate $\lambda$. It seems a bit cumbersome to evaluate 
\begin{equation}
E[\log(Z!)],
\end{equation}
where '!' denotes the factorial operation. Is there any easy way to compute this?

Comment: seems, like your expected value is the second addend of entropy of Poisson distribution: $H_\lambda (X)=\lambda[1-ln\lambda]+e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^kln(k!)}{k!}$, so you need study entropy.

Comment: @serg_1 Yes, exactly! It was while studying entropy of a Poisson distribution that this came up. When you say I need to study entropy, what aspect of the study must I focus on?